# The most trivial self-hosted REST-like web service in Scala?

Tags: scala

I have a function of the form:

```
(inp:CaseClass) => SomeOtherCaseClass
```

In other words, it takes a function with a single argument whose type is a Case Class. It returns a single value whose argument is a different kind of case class.

Just about every public function in my application will be of this form.

I'd like to expose this as a web-service so that a client can use this function by HTTP-Posting some JSON. The client will receive the response as a JSON encoded document.

An ideal solution will be:

- Simple (e.g. few lines of code, using mostly non-obscure language features)
- Should automatically marshal and unmarshal JSON - I don't want to have to write manual converters.
- As easy to use as Flask (a popular Python micro-framework for web-stuff).

Things I don't yet care about:

- High performance
- Authentication / Encryption

I do have a working implementation based on Scalatra. It's OK-ish, but not particularly pretty because it includes quite a bit of boilerplate code just to make it start a server. I'm wondering if I can go for something even more minimal.

This solution was based on some 3-year old code samples I found at work. I'm sure that there must be something more appropriate which has been developed in the last few years?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at [akka-http](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala.html). It's relatively new (rewrite of the now obsolete spray library) and has a large support community. It's easy to get started for your simple use case but if you ever need more advanced features in the future, they're probably supported. JSON de-/serialization is done using [spray-json adapter](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/common/json-support.html). You may also use other libraries, like [circe](https://github.com/circe/circe) with minimal amount of boilerplate. Here's a simple web server implementation accepting POST requests (copied from [here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/scala/http/introduction.html)):

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.Done
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Route
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.StatusCodes
import akka.http.scaladsl.marshallers.sprayjson.SprayJsonSupport._
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol._

import scala.io.StdIn

import scala.concurrent.Future

object WebServer {

  // domain model
  final case class Item(name: String, id: Long)
  final case class Order(items: List[Item])

  // formats for unmarshalling and marshalling
  implicit val itemFormat = jsonFormat2(Item)
  implicit val orderFormat = jsonFormat1(Order)

  // (fake) async database query api
  def fetchItem(itemId: Long): Future[Option[Item]] = ???
  def saveOrder(order: Order): Future[Done] = ???

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    // needed to run the route
    implicit val system = ActorSystem()
    implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
    // needed for the future map/flatmap in the end
    implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher

    val route: Route =
      get {
        pathPrefix("item" / LongNumber) { id =>
          // there might be no item for a given id
          val maybeItem: Future[Option[Item]] = fetchItem(id)

          onSuccess(maybeItem) {
            case Some(item) => complete(item)
            case None       => complete(StatusCodes.NotFound)
          }
        }
      } ~
        post {
          path("create-order") {
            entity(as[Order]) { order =>
              val saved: Future[Done] = saveOrder(order)
              onComplete(saved) { done =>
                complete("order created")
              }
            }
          }
        }

    val bindingFuture = Http().bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 8080)
    println(s"Server online at http://localhost:8080/\nPress RETURN to stop...")
    StdIn.readLine() // let it run until user presses return
    bindingFuture
      .flatMap(_.unbind()) // trigger unbinding from the port
      .onComplete(_ ⇒ system.terminate()) // and shutdown when done

  }
}
```

Does this suit your needs?